# Initialize a CGImage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

People have been saying I need to init `cameraView2` as a CGImage. I am fairly new involving Swift syntax, could anyone help out?

Note: `cameraView` is the UIImageView of `cameraView2` which is supposed to be the CGImage conversion (if that makes sense).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photosButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var crosshair: UIImageView!
    ///var cameraView2 = CGImage(named: "cameraView")
    //init(cameraView: CGImage)
    //var crosshair2: CGPoint!
    //var cameraView2: CGImage!
    //var cameraView2 = CGImage(UIImageView: cameraView)
```

The /// comments are the ones that don't work. The CGImage `cameraView2` supposed to pass through a function:

```
        guard let CGImage = cameraView2, let provider = CGImage.dataProvider else {
            return nil
       }
```

I look forward to hearing from you guys. Thanks.

Comment: **What** image should `cameraView2` store? Surely not just _any_ image, right?

Comment: It needs to store the image taken which is cameraView.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the image of a image view to a `CGImage`:

```
cameraView.image?.cgImage
```

However, if you assign that to `cameraView2` alongside the commented lines, it won't work. You need to do the assignment after an image has been put into `cameraView`. You should know when that is.

```
// declare this alongside the IBOutlets
var cameraView2: CGImage?

...

// assign cameraView.image?.cgImage when cameraView actually has an image
cameraView2 = cameraView.image?.cgImage
```

Comment: Just inserted ```cameraView2 = cameraView.image?.cgImage``` in the function a line above ```guard let CGImage = cameraView2, let provider = CGImage.dataProvider else {
            return nil
       }``` and the app is just black now. "Thread 1: "[<Color_Detector.ViewController 0x104707290> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cameraView2.""

Comment: @codingforsalary That error seems to be caused by another part of your code that you didn't show, possibly the storyboard? Did you have a connection in the storyboard called "camera2"?

Comment: I had an action (by mistake) and just removed it. Now it runs, but unfortunately the the program is still not returning my RGB via CGPoint on CGImage.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at the guard and inspecting the values of variables at that point. Is `cameraView2` nil? If it is, then the image hasn't been taken yet. If it is not nil, then you did something wrong in "returning my RGB via CGPoint on CGImage", whatever that is. @codingforsalary

Comment: Whenever I click on the camera actually it reads this in the console: ```2021-01-13 21:01:25.113734-0500 Color Detector[17055:4324721] [Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}``` but the tap gesture with the crosshairs still move and stuff (but does not display RGB return value in the console)

Comment: @codingforsalary Looks like the problem of converting `cameraView` to `CGImage` is solved isn't it? As for "returning my RGB via CGPoint on CGImage", that would be a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Comment: Just posted it. Should be on my profile, if you're interested!